# Custom NSButton image effects for pressed/disabled

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsimage, nsbutton

If I assign an image to an `NSButton` it is displayed with nice pressed and disabled effects.

In my custom `NSButton`, that should display image1+title+image2, I override `drawRect:`, but how do I obtain the **exact same** system effects for the two images?

I plan to use `NSImage` `drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:`, it would be nice if it had an pressed/disabled/effect argument...